# How can I log "NLOG" to Teamcity?

Tags: .net, teamcity, nlog

I currently have this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
     logger.Debug("Failed to log screenshot.");
}
```

But this code doesn't appear on TeamCity log.
How can I make it appear?

Comment: Where is this code running? Is it code executed in a unit test by TeamCity?

I would suggest consulting the Teamcity documentation on logging, and contacting teamcity support.

Comment: You may be using the same logging api as TeamCity, which may cause some issues. You can maybe use console print or a different logging api.